# Conceptual description of the isotypical component

Tags: representation-theory

This is probably rather simple but I have not found it in the literature.

Consider the category $C$ of representations of a finite group $G,$ over a field $k$ of characteristic not dividing the order of $G$ (so that the category is semi-simple). Fix an irreducible representation $L$ of $G.$

Is there a nice abstract description of the functor $F: C \to C$ sending a representation $V$ to its component associated to $L$ (and similarly for morphisms)? I mean $F(V)$ is naturally isomorphic to $L \otimes_k Hom_G(L,V),$ but is there a more conceptual way to write it? Perhaps using adjoint functors?

Comment: For any (not necessarily irreducible) $L$, the functor $L\otimes_k\_$ (from vector spaces to $C$) is left adjoint to $Hom_G(L,\_)$ (from $C$ to vector spaces) if that's what you mean

Comment: What is not conceptual in $L\otimes _k\mathrm{Hom}_G(L,V)$???

Answer (score 4):

I approve Ben's answer, and I would add that the center of an algebra can be interpreted as the endomorphisms of the identity functor. So if you have a central idempotent, taking the image you get an endofunctor which is a projector. This applies in particular to group algebras. For a primitive central idempotent, in the semisimple case you get a "projection to isotypical component" functor, while in the modular case you get a "projection to a block" functor.

Answer (score 2):

In the group algebra, the sum $e=\frac{\chi(e)}{\#G}\sum \bar\chi(g)g$ for an irreducible character $\chi$ is an idempotent and central (by the orthogonality relations).  (**NOTE:** I just fixed the formula above.)  The same relations show that the image of $e$ acting on any representation (which is a subrepresentation by centrality) is the isotypic component for $\chi$.

Comment: Could you explain, why $e$ is an idempotent, i. e. how it follows from the orthogonality relations? When I plug in the definitions, I get $e^2 = (\# G)^{-2} \sum_{g}\left(\sum_{h}\bar\chi(gh^{-1})\bar\chi(h)\right) g$, but I don't see why this should be $e$ (or any multiple thereof)…

Comment: @user218931 The fact that $e$ is central means it acts by a scalar on each irrep.  You can check what that scalar is by taking trace on each irrep, which gives the character inner product of $\chi$ and the character of the irrep (so 0 unless $\chi$ is the character).  Doing this calculation shows that I was off by a factor of $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ (I wrote this answer off the cuff).  There must be some clever way of proving this directly, but thinking about the reps is easier.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still feel a little uneasy with this; it should be possible to compute that $e$ is idempotent directly using the orthogonality relations as you said, but I fail to see this… Or is your argument that, what you consider orthogonality relations? I have never thought about it that way.

Comment: I agree with your point; presumably there is some clever way of doing this I'm not seeing at the moment.  However, there's nothing to be uneasy about: an element of a semi-simple algebra is an idempotent if and only if it acts as an idempotent on every simple representation (since the left regular rep is a sum of simples); for a central element (which $e$ obviously is), this means it acts by 1 or 0 on every simple irrep.  That $e$ acts by 1 on a single irrep and 0 on every other is just a restatement of first orthogonality (take the trace).