# Central idempotent of a group representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Given a finite group $G$ with representation $\rho: G \mapsto V$, and let $\chi$ be the character of an irreducible representation. It is well known that the following map
$$\pi = \frac{\chi(1)}{|G|} \sum_g \chi(g) \rho(g)$$
is the projection into the isotypical component of $\rho$ corresponding to $\chi$, but I cannot find a self-contained proof of this fact. In particular, is there a direct way to show that $\pi^2 = \pi$?

Comment: [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1180690/81360) on an old answer seems promising

Comment: Based on that thread, it should be possible to show that
$$
\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g)\chi(g^{-1}h) = \frac{|G| \chi(h)}{\chi(1)}.
$$
This would be enough to show that $\pi^2 = \pi$

Comment: seems that there is a typo in the formula and the $ \chi(g) $ should really be $ \chi(g^{-1}) $ equivalently the complex conjugate $ \overline{\chi(g)} $.

Answer (score 4):

Note $\mathrm{End}(V)\cong V\otimes V^{\ast}$ as $G$-bimodules, and $\cong V^{\oplus\dim V}$ as a $G$-module (aka rep).

The map $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\bigoplus\limits_{\small V\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}\mathrm{End}(V)$ extending $g\mapsto\rho_{\small V}(g)$ linearly is an algebra isomorphism.

Thus, the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G]\cong\bigoplus V^{\oplus \dim V}$ as left $G$-modules.

Suppose $e_{\small V}$ is the idempotent of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, corresponding to the identity map on the irrep $V$ and to the zero endomorphism on other irreps. Write $e_{\small V}=\sum a_g g$. Multiply by $h^{-1}$, and apply $\mathrm{tr}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}$.

To take the trace on the RHS, write multiplication-by-$h^{-1}g$ as a matrix using $G$ as a basis, and note the diagonals are either all $0$ (if $h^{-1}g$ is nontrivial) or all $1$ (if $h^{-1}g$ is the identity element of $G$), giving a trace of $0$ or $|G|$ respectively. More generally, if $X$ is a $G$-set, then multiplication-by-$g$'s trace as an endomorphism is the number of fixed points of $g$ acting on $X$.

To take the trace on the LHS, note $\mathrm{tr}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(x)=\sum (\dim V)\mathrm{tr}_{\small V}(x)$ because of how the regular representation decomposes as a left $G$-module. Therefore, we get

$$ (\dim V)\chi_{\small V}(h^{-1})=a_h|G|. $$

Solving for $a_h$ above we can write $e_{\small V}$ in full:

$$ e_{\small V}=\frac{\dim V}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{\small V}(g^{-1})g $$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "suppose $e_{\small V}$ is the idempotent of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, corresponding to the identity map on the irrep $V$ and to the zero endomorphism on other irreps". My rep theory is very rusty but I think this should be spelled out a bit more.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The map $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\bigoplus \mathrm{End}(V)$ being an isomoprhism means there is an element of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ that acts as the identity map when applied to the irrep $V$ but acts as the zero endomoprhism on any other irrep. (This is what the whole question is about.)

Comment: I would say that it's another perspective on what the whole question is about.  I think I was confused because you had just finished explaining that $\mathbb{C}[G]\cong\bigoplus V^{\oplus \dim V}$, and then went back to treating $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as a sum of hom spaces.  In any case, it's clear now; thank you for clarifying. Also, now that I understand all the pieces it's a very nice answer.

Comment: Your $e_V$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb C[G]$, but my $\pi$ is an endomorphsim of a specific (reducible) representation $V$. How can I reconcile these two facts?

Comment: @maroxe My $e_{\small V}$s are elements of $\Bbb C[G]$. (Of course when I take the trace over $\Bbb C[G]$ I am technically referring to the trace of multiplication-by-$e_{\small V}$ on the regular rep $\Bbb C[G]$.) Every element of $\Bbb C[G]$ can be (re)interpreted an element of ${\rm End}(V)$ (now for any $V$) by applying $\rho$ to every $g$ in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

While there is already an excellent answer, I wanted to add how the statement follows from the Schur orthogonality relations in an elementary way. Let $\lambda$ be an irreducible unitary representation of $G$ and $\chi:= \operatorname{tr}\circ \lambda$ be the corresponding character.
The Schur orthogonality relations for matrix elements of such representations read (in part)

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\lambda}_{ij}(g) \lambda_{kl}(g) = \frac{|G|}{\chi(e)} \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}.
\end{equation*}

This statement is sometimes called "Great Orthogonality Theorem".
From here it is straightforward to show the relation indicated by Ben Grossmann in his comment:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\chi(g^{-1}h)
&=\sum_{g\in G} \operatorname{tr}(\lambda(g)) \operatorname{tr}(\lambda(g^{-1})\lambda(h))\\
&=\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{i,j,k} \lambda_{ii}(g) \overline{\lambda}_{jk}(g) \lambda_{jk}(h)\\
&=\sum_{i,j,k}\left( \sum_{g\in G}\overline{\lambda}_{jk}(g) \lambda_{ii}(g) \right) \lambda_{jk}(h)\\
&=\sum_{i,j,k}\frac{|G|}{\chi(e)} \delta_{ji}\delta_{ki}\lambda_{jk}(h)\\
&= \frac{|G|}{\chi(e)}\chi(h).
\end{align*}

Showing $\pi^2 = \pi$ is now a routine computation.